# angular6-json-schema-form issue with multi-select form change event

Tags: angular, jsonschema, multi-select, formarray, angular6-json-schema-form

The current implementation for multi-select doesn't show  `<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>` because [here](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#default-form-types) for type 'array' and 'enum' it shows 'checkboxes'. 
So, I have overridden that behavior in the following way:

```
myCustomWidgets = {
    submit: NoneComponent,
    checkboxes: CustomMultiSelectComponent 
  };
```

I have created a MaterialSelectComponent file which is a copy of the same file from 'angular6-json-schema-form' and then added the custom widget like below.

```
<json-schema-form loadExternalAssets="true"
                      [schema]="formData?.schema"
                      [form]="formData?.form"
                      framework="material-design"
                      [widgets]="myCustomWidgets"
                      (isValid)="isFormValid($event)"
                      (onChanges)="onFormChange($event)"
                      (onSubmit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
    </json-schema-form>
```

I have 4 elements, one text, one date, one single select, and one multi-select like below.

```
    {
    "form": [{
            "type": "section",
            "htmlClass": "row",
            "items": [{
                    "type": "section",
                    "htmlClass": "col-xs-6 item-padding",
                    "items": ["my_text"]
                }, {
                    "type": "section",
                    "htmlClass": "col-xs-6 item-padding",
                    "items": ["my_date"]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "type": "section",
            "htmlClass": "row",
            "items": [{
                    "type": "section",
                    "htmlClass": "col-xs-6 item-padding",
                    "items": ["my_multi_select"]
                }, {
                    "type": "section",
                    "htmlClass": "col-xs-6 item-padding",
                    "items": ["my_single_select"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "schema": {
        "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Form Details",
        "description": "",
        "properties": {
            "my_multi_select": {
                "titleSource": "my_multi_select",
                "fieldDisplay": "Select More",
                "title": "Select More",
                "type": "array",
                "pattern": null,
                "description": "Multi Select",
                "format": "",
                "required": false,
                "multiple": true,
                "uniqueItems": true,
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                },
                "readonly": false
            },
            "my_text": {
                "titleSource": "my_text",
                "fieldDisplay": "My Text",
                "title": "My Text",
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "",
                "description": "Enter Text",
                "format": "",
                "required": true,
                "readonly": false
            },
            "my_date": {
                "titleSource": "my_date",
                "fieldDisplay": "My Date",
                "title": "My Date",
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "",
                "description": "Enter Date",
                "format": "date",
                "required": true,
                "readonly": false
            },
            "my_single_select": {
                "titleSource": "my_single_select",
                "fieldDisplay": "My Single Select",
                "title": "My Single Select",
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "",
                "description": "Enter Date",
                "format": "date",
                "required": true,
                "readonly": false,
                "enum": [
                    "One",
                    "Two",
                    "Three",
                    "Four"
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": ["my_text", "my_date", "my_single_select"]
    },
    "data": {
        "my_text": "",
        "my_date": "",
        "my_single_select": "",
        "my_multi_select" : []
    }
}
```

Now the issue is it's not capturing the data change event in method *form-group.functions.ts* file only for that "my_multi_select" element. For the rest of the 3 elements any change is getting a callback and the values are getting captured. I have debugged here below *json-schema.form.services.ts* where all the controls are getting registered for subscription. In my 4 elements, multi-select is of type "FormArray" and rest are "FormControl".

```
buildFormGroup() {
    this.formGroup = <FormGroup>buildFormGroup(this.formGroupTemplate);
    if (this.formGroup) {
      this.compileAjvSchema();
      this.validateData(this.formGroup.value);

      // Set up observables to emit data and validation info when form data changes
      if (this.formValueSubscription) { this.formValueSubscription.unsubscribe(); }
      this.formValueSubscription = this.formGroup.valueChanges
        .subscribe(formValue => this.validateData(formValue));
    }
  }
```

Is there a known bug with FormArray type subscription or event emitter?

I have also tried to use ViewChild to get the values, but I still only get the values of others except that Multi-Select. I still don't understand that in the UI when I select multiple values it still shows there, which means it's stored somewhere (may be in controlValue) but why there is no way to access that value (without onchange event)?

```
<json-schema-form #myJsonSchema
                          loadExternalAssets="true"
                          [schema]="formData?.schema"
                          [form]="formData?.form"
                          framework="material-design"
                          [widgets]="myCustomWidgets"
                          (isValid)="isFormValid($event)"
                          (onChanges)="onFormChange($event)"
                          (onSubmit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
        </json-schema-form>
```

Comment: I guess I have to stop using this framework.

Comment: Can you add more code, such as the component code?  Maybe put it up on StackBlitz?

Comment: I am using Angular7 with angular6-json-schema-form 7.3.0. I have seen StackBlitz got Angular8. I shall work on that and try to add the full code in there and would share the link as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

One guy from my team fixed this issue. Please see below the component code. 
Basically the Checkboxes code was used here to emit the values. **selectionChange()** method was used for this as shown in the code. We had faced another issue with the data binding as well which we had fixed it adding **value**

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {buildTitleMap, isArray, JsonSchemaFormService} from 'angular6-json-schema-form';
import {Component, Inject, Input, OnInit, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'material-select-widget',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field
      [appearance]="options?.appearance || matFormFieldDefaultOptions?.appearance || 'standard'"
      [class]="options?.htmlClass || ''"
      [floatLabel]="options?.floatLabel || matLabelGlobalOptions?.float || (options?.notitle ? 'never' : 'auto')"
      [hideRequiredMarker]="options?.hideRequired ? 'true' : 'false'"
      [style.width]="'100%'">
      <mat-label *ngIf="!options?.notitle">{{options?.title}}</mat-label>
      <span matPrefix *ngIf="options?.prefix || options?.fieldAddonLeft"
            [innerHTML]="options?.prefix || options?.fieldAddonLeft"></span>
      <mat-select *ngIf="boundControl"
                  [attr.aria-describedby]="'control' + layoutNode?._id + 'Status'"
                  [attr.name]="controlName"
                  [id]="'control' + layoutNode?._id"
                  [multiple]="options?.multiple"
                  [placeholder]="options?.notitle ? options?.placeholder : options?.title"
                  [required]="options?.required"
                  [style.width]="'100%'"
                  [(value)]="selectedValues"
                  (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
                  (blur)="options.showErrors = true">
        <ng-template ngFor let-selectItem [ngForOf]="selectList">
          <mat-option *ngIf="!isArray(selectItem?.items)"
                      [value]="selectItem?.value">
            <span [innerHTML]="selectItem?.name"></span>
          </mat-option>
          <mat-optgroup *ngIf="isArray(selectItem?.items)"
                        [label]="selectItem?.group">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let subItem of selectItem.items"
                        [value]="subItem?.value">
              <span [innerHTML]="subItem?.name"></span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-optgroup>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-select *ngIf="!boundControl"
                  [attr.aria-describedby]="'control' + layoutNode?._id + 'Status'"
                  [attr.name]="controlName"
                  [disabled]="controlDisabled || options?.readonly"
                  [id]="'control' + layoutNode?._id"
                  [multiple]="options?.multiple"
                  [placeholder]="options?.notitle ? options?.placeholder : options?.title"
                  [required]="options?.required"
                  [style.width]="'100%'"
                  [value]="controlValue"
                  (blur)="options.showErrors = true"
                  (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
        <ng-template ngFor let-selectItem [ngForOf]="selectList">
          <mat-option *ngIf="!isArray(selectItem?.items)"
                      [attr.selected]="selectItem?.value === controlValue"
                      [value]="selectItem?.value">
            <span [innerHTML]="selectItem?.name"></span>
          </mat-option>
          <mat-optgroup *ngIf="isArray(selectItem?.items)"
                        [label]="selectItem?.group">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let subItem of selectItem.items"
                        [attr.selected]="subItem?.value === controlValue"
                        [value]="subItem?.value">
              <span [innerHTML]="subItem?.name"></span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-optgroup>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-select>
      <span matSuffix *ngIf="options?.suffix || options?.fieldAddonRight"
            [innerHTML]="options?.suffix || options?.fieldAddonRight"></span>
      <mat-hint *ngIf="options?.description && (!options?.showErrors || !options?.errorMessage)"
                align="end" [innerHTML]="options?.description"></mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="options?.showErrors && options?.errorMessage"
               [innerHTML]="options?.errorMessage"></mat-error>`,
  styles: [`
    mat-error {
      font-size: 75%;
      margin-top: -1rem;
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    ::ng-deep json-schema-form mat-form-field .mat-form-field-wrapper .mat-form-field-flex
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      width: initial;
    }
  `],
})
export class CustomMultiSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: AbstractControl;
  controlName: string;
  controlValue: any;
  controlDisabled = false;
  boundControl = false;
  options: any;
  selectList: any[] = [];
  isArray = isArray;
  @Input() layoutNode: any;
  @Input() layoutIndex: number[];
  @Input() dataIndex: number[];

  selectedValues = []

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) @Optional() public matFormFieldDefaultOptions,
    @Inject(MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS) @Optional() public matLabelGlobalOptions,
    private jsf: JsonSchemaFormService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.layoutNode.options || {};

    this.selectList = buildTitleMap(
      this.options.titleMap || this.options.enumNames,
      this.options.enum, !!this.options.required, !!this.options.flatList
    );

    this.jsf.initializeControl(this, !this.options.readonly);
    if (!this.options.notitle && !this.options.description && this.options.placeholder) {
      this.options.description = this.options.placeholder;
    }
    if (this.boundControl) {
      const formArray = this.jsf.getFormControl(this);
      for (const selectItem of this.selectList) {
        selectItem.checked = formArray.value.includes(selectItem.value);
      }
    }

    this.selectedValues = this.selectList.filter(item => item.checked)
                                         .map(item => item.value);
  }

  selectionChange(event) {
    this.options.showErrors = true;
    this.selectList.map(item => item.checked = this.selectedValues.includes(item.value));
    if (this.boundControl) {
      this.jsf.updateArrayCheckboxList(this, this.selectList);
    }
  }

}
```

I hope this helps you guys. Anyone can use this code. I am going to add a PR to the angular6-json-schema-form project.